# How can I change the colour of a symbol after a TouchEvent?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, air

I'm completely new to ActionScript 3 and was wondering if someone could point out why this is not working.

```
colourButton.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, colour);

function colour(event:TouchEvent):void {
    monster.Transform.colorTransform = 0xFF0000;
}
```

Comment: Please add some Information about what do you expect and what it do yet

Answer (score 0):

This line lacks basic research effort:

```
monster.Transform.colorTransform = 0xFF0000;
```

[`DisplayObject`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html) does not have a `.Transform` property. Type `monster` to a non `dynamic` type to receive error messages about that.

There *is* a [`.transform`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#transform) property, which has a [`.colorTransform`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Transform.html#colorTransform) property. The thing is that this property is of type [`ColorTransform`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/ColorTransform.html). You cannot assign it an integer value like `0xFF0000` as you do now, because integers aren't ColorTransforms. Just like apples aren't oranges.

Instead, you should assign a `ColorTransform` object to that property. Check the documentation on it (linked above) to see how you can create the desired effect. There's more to it then specifying a single color value.